# -Verbose not working with my Pester Test in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, verbose, pester

I wrote a pester test to check that certain folders and files exist.  The pester test works great but I wanted to include suggestions for fixes if the test is called with the -Verbose option.  But I can't seem to get the -Verbose parameter to the actual test.

Folder/File structure:

```
Custom-PowerShellModule
    |   Custom-PowerShellModule.psd1
    |   Custom-PowerShellModule.psm1
    \---Tests
            Module.Tests.ps1
```

Below is just the top part of pester test:

```
$Here = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"

Describe "Module Minimum Requirements Tests.  Use -Verbose for Suggested Fixes" -Tags Module {
  Context "Test:  Verify File Counts = 1" {
    Write-Verbose  "If you receive an error, verify there is only 'ONE' PSD1 File and only 'ONE' PSM1 File."
    It "There is only one PSD1 file" { (Get-ChildItem "$Here\..\" *.psd1).count | Should be 1 }
    It "There is only one PSM1 file" { (Get-ChildItem "$Here\..\" *.psm1).count | Should be 1 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the other answer, it doesn't seem to be possible to use `Write-Verbose` when running the script with the `Invoke-Pester` command. I think this may be because using the `Invoke-Pester` command means that you script is interpreted rather than directly executed by the PowerShell engine. The next best alternative would be to add in `If` statements that perform the same checks as your tests and then use `Write-Host` or `Write-Warning` to give instructions if they are negative. I have done that occasionally in the past.

You can however use `-verbose` if you are executing the script directly (e.g just directly running the *.tests.ps1 file). However to do so you need to add `[cmdletbinding()]` and a Param block to the top of your script:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$Here = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"

Describe "Module Minimum Requirements Tests.  Use -Verbose for Suggested Fixes" -Tags Module {
  Context "Test:  Verify File Counts = 1" {

    Write-Verbose  "If you receive an error, verify there is only 'ONE' PSD1 File and only 'ONE' PSM1 File."

    It "There is only one PSD1 file" { (Get-ChildItem "$Here\..\" *.psd1).count | Should be 1 }
    It "There is only one PSM1 file" { (Get-ChildItem "$Here\..\" *.psm1).count | Should be 1 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-Verbose` switch of the `Invoke-Pester` cmdlet is not available inside the test cases. You have to explicitly pass this for the test case to access.

Here is an example based on your script:

```
Param([Bool]$Verbose)

Describe "Module Minimum Requirements Tests.  Use -Verbose for Suggested Fixes" -Tags Module {
    Context "Test:  Verify File Counts = 1" {
    Write-Verbose  "If you receive an error, verify there is only 'ONE' PSD1 File and only 'ONE' PSM1 File." -Verbose:$Verbose
    It "There is only one PSD1 file" { (Get-ChildItem "$Here\..\" *.psd1).count | Should be 1 }
    It "There is only one PSM1 file" { (Get-ChildItem "$Here\..\" *.psm1).count | Should be 1 }
   }
}

Invoke-Pester -Script @{Path='path' ; Parameters = @{ Verbose = $True }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explictly passing the Verbose flag to test cases, you can also change the default value of VerbosePreference in scope:

```
$VerbosePreference = $Env:MyVerbosePreference
```

Then you can control it from outside:

```
$Env:MyVerbosePreference= 'Continue'
Invoke-Pester ...
```